# How to add MultiPolygons along with Bubble Layer or (any point data) in azure-maps?

Tags: angular, azure-maps

I'm trying to display MultiPolygon Layer(data in geojson format) along with Bubble Layer(data in geojson format) in the map. However the map is not rendering the polygons. I'm developing my application in Angular.  Am I missing something in the below code ? Please help.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'azure-maps-final';
map: any;
pointData = [];
datasource: any;
policyDataSource: any;
policyData = [];
bubbleLayer: any;
polygonLayer: any;
constructor(public mapService: MapService) {}

getMap() {
this.map = new atlas.Map('map', {
  center: [-97, 39],
  zoom: 3,
  style: 'satellite',
  view: 'Auto',

  authOptions: {
    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
    subscriptionKey: 'my-subscription-key',
  },
  });

this.map.events.add('ready', () => {
  this.datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();

  this.map.sources.add(this.datasource);
  this.policyDataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
  this.map.sources.add(this.policyDataSource);

  //console.log(this.policyDataSource);
  this.polygonLayer = new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(
    this.policyDataSource,
    'myPolygonLayer',
    {
      fillColor: 'rgba(255,165,0,0.2)',
    }
  );
  this.bubbleLayer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(
    this.datasource,
    'myBubbleLayer',
    {
      color: 'orange',
      radius: 5,
      outlineColor: 'white',
      outlineWidth: 2,
    }
  );

  console.log(this.bubbleLayer);
  console.log(this.polygonLayer);
  this.datasource.add(this.pointData);
  this.policyDataSource.add(this.policyData);
  this.map.layers.add([this.bubbleLayer, this.polygonLayer]);
});
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.mapService.pointData$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.pointData = data;
 });
 this.mapService.policyData$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.policyData = data
  this.getMap();
 });
 }
```

Point Data is my Bubble Layer containing all the points, and policy data is my Polygon datasource.
Console logging the layers shows the array with the coordinate points . Attaching the image -
[console log of polygon layer showing coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tru6S.jpg)

How to enable the rendering of polygon layer ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the shapes in your data source points or polygon/MultiPolygons? Polygon layer will only render Polygon/MultiPolygon shapes, not individual points.

Comment: Also worth noting that your polygon fill color is pretty transparent, so that may make polygons difficult to see. Also, polygon layer only renders the fill area of a polygon. If you are looking for the outline of each polygon, use a line layer with the polygon data too.

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt , thanks for your comment. I have added the geoJson object as this.policyDataSource.add(new atlas.data.MultiPolygon(this.policyData));  . policyData is the  polygon geoJson object.  Now the geometry type of the layer is "MultiPolygon" and the individual features in the coordinates property has the geometry type as "Polygon". And  I changed the opacity levels to 0.5 . It is not rendering the polygons to the map. The point and polygons are two different datasources.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `this.policyData` is an 3-dimensional array of positions, it shouldn't be passed into the MultiPolygon class. If `this.policyData` is a array or feature collection of shapes, you can add that directly to the data source like `this.policyDataSource.add(this.policyData);`

If `this.policyData` is a feature collection of polygons, and you want to convert it into a multipolygon for some reason (not sure why you want to do this), you will have to create and array and loop through each polygon and add its coordinates values to the array. For example:

```js
var polygonFeatureCollection = this.policyData;

var multiPolygonCoords = [];

polygonFeatureCollection.features.forEach(polygon => {
    multiPolygonCoords.push(polygon.geometry.coordinates);
});

this.policyDataSource.add(new atlas.data.MultiPolygon(multiPolygonCoords));
```